# Как по-хитрому распарсить битый XML?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Довелось тут работать с битыми svg-файлами, в которых в большом количестве имеются ошибки двух видов:

1. Забыли закрыть тег: `<svg><g>foo</svg>`
2. Два раза закрыли тег: `<svg><g>foo</g></g>bar</svg>`

Когда столкнулся с первым типом ошибки, я воспользовался встроенной в lxml фичей:

```
parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
svg = lxml.etree.XML(svgdata, parser=parser)
```

Ктоорая выдаёт `<svg><g>foo</g></svg>` и всё типа хорошо.

Однако, когда я столкнулся со вторым типом ошибки, там оно выдало `<svg><g>foo</g></svg>`, то есть потеряло `bar` (часть файла после закрытого тега). А мне бы хотелось получить-таки `<svg><g>foo</g>bar</svg>`.

Есть ли готовые решения для починки обоих типов ошибок или отправляться пилить свой велосипед?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться BeautifulSoup:

Код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
badString = "<svg><g>foo</g></g>bar</svg>"
print(BeautifulSoup(badString, 'lxml').html.body.next)
```

Результат:

```
# <svg><g>foo</g>bar</svg>
```

Comment: `<html><body>` ох-ох)

Comment: отрезать думаю не проблема)). Исправил ответ

Comment: `BeautifulSoup()` особенно, если указать `html5lib`, может распознать достаточно широкий набор сломанных html/xml документов.